# Merge two m4a File into one file in Xamarin.Android using C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, m4a

I wanted to merge two(multiple) m4a extension audio file into one file.

I am using Xamarin.Android and C# for that.

I have written a code to read the file bytes and merging that bytes into one.

But the result will not generating and merge file.

Is direct reading bytes from file and merge/combined that bytes into one file will work or i have to use some different approach for that ?

Can anybody please guide me for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about appending one audio file to the end of another, or "mixing" two audio tracks so they play at the same time

Comment: Yes I want to append one file to the end of another. Not mixing.

Comment: @Brijesh did you manage to append files? I am facing similar issue. Any help?